# How to sent value on Select to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I want to get value from select.js to index.js i have no idea to get it on index.js

Select.js

```
const SelectSmall = () => {
const [ProJect, setProJect] = React.useState("");


return (
  <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 150 }} size="small">
    <h1>{ProJect}</h1>
    <InputLabel id="Projects">Project</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="Projects"
      id="Projects"
      value={ProJect}
      label="Project" 
      onChange={e=>setProJect(e.target.value)}
      
    >
      <MenuItem value="">
        <em>None</em>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'ma'}>MA-Network</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'ns'}>Network-Security</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'fz'}>Freezone</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'ma-2'}>MA-Network2</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
);
}

  export default SelectSmall;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import SelectSmall from "./select"
export const App> = () => {
return (
   <div>
     <h1><SelectSmall.Project><h1>

   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please provide code for index.js as well, you will have to use props for exchanging the data between index.js and select.js you can pass method from index.js to select.js and then call that method in select.js or you can also pass variable from index.js to select.js using props and then set its value in select.js

Comment: i just want only value not form on select.js

Comment: use redux or useContext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Select` component you need to add one more function via its properties to send the value to the parent component

```
const SelectSmall = props => {
```

.
.
.

```
<Select
      labelId="Projects"
      id="Projects"
      value={ProJect}
      label="Project" 
      onChange={e=> handleValueChange(e)}
    >
```

.
.
.

```
const handleValueChange = e => {
  setProJect(e.target.value)
  props.getValue(e.target.value)
}
```

And the add a new function in parent component to use this new value

```
import React from 'react'
import SelectSmall from "./select"
export const App> = () => {
 
const printSelectValue = val => {
  console.log(val)
}

return (
   <div>
     <h1><SelectSmall getValue={printSelectValue}><h1>

   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: props.getValue is not  a function it error like this :(

Comment: it's here `<h1><SelectSmall getValue={printSelectValue}><h1>` in index js

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtfulness, you’ve made my day!